# Any rigorous books on geometric calculus

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, book-recommendation, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Are there any rigorous books on analysis bases on geometric/Clifford algebra? I am searching for one which contains a detailed proof of theorems like stokes' theorem and the helmholtz decomposition.

Thank you!

Something fun in the process:
I thought the subject could be called geometric analysis or Clifford analysis, but both turned out to be different subjects already.

Comment: check the controversies at the comments of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210804/is-hesteness-geometric-algebra-widely-accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Sobczyk)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4526), and [Geometric Algebra for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometric-algebra-for-physicists/FB8D3ACB76AB3AB10BA7F27505925091).  In his book, [Vector and Geometric Calculus](http://www.faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/vagc/index.html), Alan MacDonald does a really nice job building up the basics required to be able to understand the statement of the theorem.  I have a derivation of the Helmholtz decomposition in [chapter II of my book](http://peeterjoot.com/writing/geometric-algebra-for-electrical-engineers/) (which I'll claim has "an Engineer's rigor" and no more.)

Some work may be required to beef up the rigor in all these (and other sources), as noted in [MacDonald's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08274).  Spivak's "Calculus On Manifolds: A Modern Approach To Classical Theorems Of Advanced Calculus" (pg 129-130) also hints at problems with triangularization independent of geometric algebra (unbounded area for some triangularizations), and provides some references for "this tricky topic" (that I haven't read yet.)

Comment: Very interesting answer. The first paper you linked is amazing and is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you,